# Finding iPhone 3G firmware version after full reset

Tags: iphone, firmware

I "reset all settings and erased all data" on my iPhone 3G yesterday using iTunes. The phone is locked to At&t, and since I do not have a SIM from At&t, I am unable to go past the lock screen to view the firmware and the iOS version. 
What firmware and iOS version does iPhone 3G have after completely resetting it using the latest version of iTunes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Latest iOS [firmware is same as the OS in that respect] you can use on an iPhone 3G is 4.2.1 (8C148)